# How come my UIImageView is gone after I reload data on UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nslayoutconstraint

I set the content in my UITableView cells dynamically depending on what data user provides. For example, if user does not provide an image, the UIImageView goes away to make the cell appear shorter. My problem is that I think the dynamic handling of my cell contents are causing the reused cells to get messed up.

I am sure the problem is because I am removing the image view from superview, but shouldn't it reset when I reload my table view? Or do I have to somehow add it back to the superview? Before I go and unnecessarily programmatically add a bunch of constraints what is the proper way to handle this? Here is the relevant code for my cell.

```
    func configureItemCell(postTitle: String, postTime: String, postDescription: String, postImageURL: String) {
        titleLabel.text = postTitle
        timePostedLabel.text = "\(postTime) by"

        if postImageURL != "" {
            postImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: postImageURL), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))

        } else {
            // Remove image view since none was specified
            postImageView.removeFromSuperview()

            // Attach constraint for description since image is now gone
            let descriptionBottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: descriptionLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.bottomMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: -12)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([descriptionBottomConstraint])
        }

        if postDescription == "" {
            // Shrink distance to 0 since description not showing
            descriptionTopConstraint.constant = 0
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to use two different cell types . One is for regular and this other is for the special.

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt 
 indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let item = items[indexPath.section]
    switch item.type {
    case .normal:
       if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Normal", for: indexPath) as? NormalCell {
     cell.item = item
     return cell
  }
    case .special:
      if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Special", for: indexPath) as? AboutCell {
     cell.item = item
     return cell
  }
```